# Displaying a raw image using CBVs in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to do some image manipulation, but before I do I want to render the image. This is what I've tried, but it does not work. The page is blank, no errors, why?

```
class ImgThumbnail(DetailView):
    queryset = Images.objects.all()

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        from PIL import Image
        import requests
        from io import BytesIO

        response = requests.get('http://example.com/media/images/{}.jpg'.format(self.pk))
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

        return HttpResponse(img, content_type='image/jpg')
```

Comment: Can you show the template?

Comment: There is no template, I want to directly render the image to the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `StreamingHttpResponse`. In a way like:

(dynamic content type and content length as bonus)

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
from django.http import HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse


class ImgThumbnail(DetailView):
    queryset = Images.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        r = requests.get('http://example.com/media/images/{}.jpg'.format(self.pk))


        if not r.status_code == 200:
            return HttpResponse('', status=r.status_code)

        wrapper = FileWrapper(StringIO(r.content))
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=r.headers.get('Content-Type'))
        response['Content-Length'] = r.headers.get('Content-Length')

        return response
```

Comment: is StringIO Python 3?

Comment: in python 3 it is part of the `io` module. see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

DetailView doesn't have a `render_to_response` method, so there is no point in defining your own.

You're not using any of the functionality of DetailView here anyway. You should inherit from the base View class, and put your code in the `get` method.

Comment: That's a good point, but detail view does seem to work. It gets the PK and returns the correct object. ``return HttpResponse(img, content_type='image/jpg')`` then skips the template part and renders ok. but as you said I could do all this in a simple view

Comment: According to CBV ``DetailView`` does have ``render_to_response `` https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

Comment: daniel is right. you should use `get` instead of `render_to_response`. you want to directly return a response - without rendering a template.

Comment: Agree, but I was referring to the comment > ``DetailView doesn't have a render_to_response method`` but the docs say it does :0 confused