# Image response from DetailView in Django

Tags: django

I'd like to have a `DetailView` respond with an image file that is saved to the model/object.

I have seen this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183311/displaying-a-raw-image-using-cbvs-in-django) but what I am doing is a little different.

I have the following model/views/urls - this allows me to display the image in an `img` tag inside a template when accessing the url `localhost/MY-SKU-FIELD`. I'd rather not use a template and just respond with the image directly.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class SignModel(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField('SKU', max_length=50)
    sign_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/sign')

# views.py
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from signs.models import SignModel

class SignDetailView(DetailView):
    model = SignModel
    template_name = 'signs/sign_detail.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'sku'
    slug_field = 'sku'

# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from signs.views import SignDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:sku>', SignDetailView.as_view(), name='sign-detail'),
]

{# 'signs/templates/sign_detail.html #}
<img src="{{object.sign_image.url}}" alt="">
```

Based on the related question/answer, I figure I need to define my own `get()` method, then fetch the image, and then respond accordingly, but I'm not quite sure how to fetch the image based on the object fetched in `DetailView`. I've tried fetching with `r = requests.get(self.sign_image.url)` but that is clearly not working.

**How do I get the image and respond correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this before but I was able to quickly check, and you can give the value of the field to a [django.http.FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) object. As for the view, I think you want to overwrite the `render_to_response` method.

```py
from django.http import FileResponse


class SignDetailView(DetailView):
    model = SignModel
    template_name = 'signs/sign_detail.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'sku'
    slug_field = 'sku'

    def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
        return FileResponse(self.object.sign_image)
```